# Reference implementation for a JMX connector?

Tags: jmx, jmxmp

I am looking to implement a JMX *connector* for an existing server project that has its own wire protocol, where the connector re-uses the same wire protocol.

Can anyone tell me where I can find the sources of a reference connector? The JMXMP implementation would be ideal as inspiration, however that's proving hard to track down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **JMXMP** sources live in [OpenDMK project](https://opendmk.java.net/)

You will need to download the zipped sources archive as there is no source repository available.